# Sequence of positive element in $C^*$-Algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra and $A_+$ be the set of positive elements of $A$. Suppose that $(a_n)$ is a sequence of $A_+$. I am trying to prove that

> $\lim_{n\to\infty}||a_n||$ exists if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists

I managed to prove the left way of the statement using this norm property:
$|\|x\|-\|y\|| \leq \|x-y\|$, but i am stuck while proving the right way. Here is what i have done.

if $\lim_{n\to\infty}||a_n||$ exists, then there is (say) $L\in \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}||a_n||=L$. My claim is that $(a_n)$ would converge to $(L)I$ where $I$ is the identity of $A$. So i start with

$||a_n-(L)I||=||a_n-\|a_n\|I+\|a_n\|I-(L)I||\leq||a_n-\|a_n\|I\|+\|\|a_n\|I-(L)I||$

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}||a_n||=L$, $\|\|a_n\|I-(L)I||=|\|a_n\|-(L)|$ approaches $0$, but i don't know what to do with $||a_n-\|a_n\|I\|$.

is there a clue to prove what i claim or my claim is not true in general?

Apologize if my english is quite a mess and thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that this statement is correct? Maybe you should add that these sequence is, say, increasing? Otherwise even in the case when $A$ is the $2\times 2$ matrix algebra and $a_{2n-1}=\mathrm{diag}(1,2)$, $a_{2n}=\mathrm{diag}(2,1)$ the statement is seem to be incorrect.

Comment: Aaaah, right. I wasn't sure at first but i kept going anyway. Perhaps i can try to prove the statement if the sequence is monotone next time. Thank you for your counterexample :D

Comment: This is almost always false. For monotone sequences it only holds in finite dimensional $C^\ast$-algebras because of compactness of the closed unit balls. In general this fails. It is an easy exercise to construct counterexamples in $C([0,1])$.